# Hibernate program still running

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

My small program terminates properly if i do not <s>begin a transaction</s> save to a transaction.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;       
    Session session = null;
    Transaction t = null;

    try{
        sessionFactory = new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(new UserInfo("garb@junkHeap.com", "password2", "erical garb"));
        t = session.getTransaction();
        t.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not create connection!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{

        DAOUtilities.closeResource(session, "Session");
        DAOUtilities.closeResource(sessionFactory, "sessionFactory");
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);

        System.out.println("Session open: " + session.isOpen());
        System.out.println("Factory open: " + sessionFactory.isOpen());
        System.out.println("Transaction active: " + t.isActive());
    }
}
```

The print statements confirm that session and sessionFactory were successfully closed and the transaction is no longer active. To my knowledge there is no way to check if registry was successfully destroyed. Here is the output...

```
Hibernate: insert into UserInfo (loggedIn, name, password, email) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Mar 24, 2017 12:37:49 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH10001008: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb]
Session open: false
Factory open: false
Transaction active: false
```

What am I missing? Any suggestions would be appriciated, Thank you.

NOTE: My database gui is detecting a one session leak per execution and changes are accurately reflected in database.

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using ?

Comment: Hibernate 5.2.9. Its the latest "stable" version. I will try using an older version but I doubt thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it existed in a database verification function I implemented a long time ago. Since open postgres sessions did not prevent my program from terminating I overlooked the error.

I implemented a session leak detector I found at https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-detect-database-connection-leaks/

The confidence it gave me in issue allowed me to find the culprit. I highly recommend implementing such a test in all programs utilizing a database. I wish I had known about this tool when I began the project, It would have saved me a lot of time. Hopefully this post will save others the time I have lost.